# How to get average of every nth lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data of thousand lines like this:

```
1.01
2.01
3.01
4.01
5.012
6.019
7.01
8.013
9.01
10.01
11.01
12.01
13.01
14.01
15.5
```

I would like to get averages of every 9 lines (or general nth line if 9 is two short). I would like to print out from the line `(n-1)/2` to line `[line_number - (n-1)/2]`, where `line_number` is the total number of lines in the data file, `n=9` for this example.
This command does not work [average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346875/average-of-every-nth-lines-bash) like what I expected:

```
line_number=$(wc -l test.txt)
awk '{sum[$1]=sum[$1] + $1; nr[$1]++} END {for (a in sum) {print a, sum[a]/nr[a]}}' test.txt
```

Expected results:

```
1.01    
2.01    
3.01    
4.01    
5.012   5.011555556 #(1.01+2.01+3.01+4.01+5.012+6.019+7.01+8.013+9.01)/9
6.019   6.011555556 #(     2.01+3.01+4.01+5.012+6.019+7.01+8.013+9.01+10.01)/9
7.01    7.011555556 #(          3.01+4.01+5.012+6.019+7.01+8.013+9.01+10.01+11.01)/9
8.013   8.011555556
9.01    9.011555556
10.01   10.01133333
11.01   11.06477778
12.01
13.01
14.01
15.5
```

Comment: starting from 1st line is fine as well. but starting from n/2 or (n-1)/2 is better for plotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP if average needs to be printed from n/2th OR n-1/2th line onwards then following will help.

```
awk -v n="9" '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
FNR==NR{
  val[FNR]=$0
  count=NR
  next
}
!till{
  from=(n%2==0?n/2:(n-1)/2)
  till=(count-from)
}
till && FNR>from{ flag=1 }
flag && FNR<=till+0{
  sum=""
  for(i=++count1;i<=count1+(n-1);i++){
    sum+=val[i]
  }
  $0=$0 OFS (sum/n)
}
1
' Input_file  Input_file
```

With shown samples output will be as follows:

```
1.01
2.01
3.01
4.01
5.012   5.01156
6.019   6.01156
7.01    7.01156
8.013   8.01156
9.01    9.01156
10.01   10.0113
11.01   11.0648
12.01
13.01
14.01
15.5
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v n="9" '                          ##Starting awk program from here, setting n to 9 here.
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}                         ##Setting OFS to \t in BEGIN section.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition if FNR==NR is TRUE here.
  val[FNR]=$0                           ##Creating val with index of FNR and its value is $0.
  count=NR                              ##Setting NR to count here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!till{                                  ##If till is NOT set then do following.
  from=(n%2==0?n/2:(n-1)/2)             ##Setting from depends upon total number of lines even or odd.
  till=(count-from)                     ##Setting till which is difference of count and from.
}
till && FNR>from{ flag=1 }              ##If till is SET and FNR is greater than from then set the flag.
flag && FNR<=till+0{                    ##Flag is set AND current line is <= till then do following.
  sum=""                                ##Nullify the sum here.
  for(i=++count1;i<=count1+(n-1);i++){  ##Starting a for loop from count1 to till value of count1+(n-1).
    sum+=val[i]                         ##keep adding val value to sum here.
  }
  $0=$0 OFS (sum/n)                     ##Adding sum/n value to current line.
}
1                                       ##printing edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file  Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: oh, I edited the question. if the raw data file has 465, it should print out from 5th line until 461th line.

Comment: @BinhThien, ok, got it, editing it now.

Comment: @BinhThien, I have added generic solution now, where `n` we can mention any number of lines sum, it worked fine for me, please do check and let me know then.

Comment: @BinhThien, once you confirm its working fine, will add detailed explanation in answer then.

Comment: thank you. I test some, your code works fine.

Comment: @BinhThien, Detailed explanation for code has been added in answer now. I believe I too tested few scenarios and it looks good to me. Let me know how it your testing going.

Comment: me2. it prints out all correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it quite simply without arrays. Simply carry a `sum` variable and then on the `nth` line, compute the average and output resetting the `sum` and `line` to `0`. For example, you could do:

```bash
awk -v nth=3 '
  {
    sum+=$1
    ++line
    printf "line: %2d  sum: %6.3f", line, sum
  }
  line == nth {
    print "   avg: " sum/nth
    line = sum = 0
    next
  }
  { print "" }
' values.txt
```

(above the value of the `nth` line to average is provided as a variable with `-v nth=3`)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `values.txt` you can run the script by pasting at the command line in the directory containing `values.txt` and would receive:

```
$ awk -v nth=3 '
>   {
>     sum+=$1
>     ++line
>     printf "line: %2d  sum: %6.3f", line, sum
>   }
>   line == nth {
>     print "   avg: " sum/nth
>     line = sum = 0
>     next
>   }
>   { print "" }
> ' values.txt
line:  1  sum:  1.010
line:  2  sum:  3.020
line:  3  sum:  6.030   avg: 2.01
line:  1  sum:  4.010
line:  2  sum:  9.022
line:  3  sum: 15.041   avg: 5.01367
line:  1  sum:  7.010
line:  2  sum: 15.023
line:  3  sum: 24.033   avg: 8.011
line:  1  sum: 10.010
line:  2  sum: 21.020
line:  3  sum: 33.030   avg: 11.01
line:  1  sum: 13.010
line:  2  sum: 27.020
line:  3  sum: 42.520   avg: 14.1733
```

Above with `nth = 3` the average is computed for every 3-lines. The line number within the running sum along with the current `sum` is printed for every line.

If you wanted to add the actual line number to your output, you could simply use `FNR` to provide it, e.g.

```bash
awk -v nth=3 '
  {
    sum+=$1
    ++line
    printf "no. %2d  line: %2d  sum: %6.3f", FNR, line, sum
  }
  line == nth {
    print "   avg: " sum/nth
    line = sum = 0
    next
  }
  { print "" }
' values.txt
```

`awk` is an amazingly flexible tool that can do just about any type text processing you need.

**Sample Output**

The first few lines of output would now be:

```
no.  1  line:  1  sum:  1.010
no.  2  line:  2  sum:  3.020
no.  3  line:  3  sum:  6.030   avg: 2.01
no.  4  line:  1  sum:  4.010
no.  5  line:  2  sum:  9.022
no.  6  line:  3  sum: 15.041   avg: 5.01367
...
```